# Is there a way to reshape an array that does not maintain the original size (or a convenient work-around)?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, error-handling, reshape

As a simplified example, suppose I have a dataset composed of 40 sorted values. The values of this example are all integers, though this is not necessarily the case for the actual dataset.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.linspace(1,40,40)
```

I am trying to find the maximum value inside the dataset for certain window sizes. The formula to compute the window sizes yields a pattern that is best executed with arrays (in my opinion). For simplicity sake, let's say the indices denoting the window sizes are a list `[1,2,3,4,5]`; this corresponds to window sizes of `[2,4,8,16,32]` (the pattern is `2**index`).

```
## this code looks long because I've provided docstrings
## just in case the explanation was unclear

def shapeshifter(num_col, my_array=data):
    """
    This function reshapes an array to have 'num_col' columns, where 
    'num_col' corresponds to index.
    """
    return my_array.reshape(-1, num_col)

def looper(num_col, my_array=data):
    """
    This function calls 'shapeshifter' and returns a list of the 
    MAXimum values of each row in 'my_array' for 'num_col' columns. 
    The length of each row (or the number of columns per row if you 
    prefer) denotes the size of each window.
    EX:
        num_col = 2
        ==> window_size = 2
        ==> check max( data[1], data[2] ),
                  max( data[3], data[4] ),
                  max( data[5], data[6] ), 
                               .
                               .
                               .
                  max( data[39], data[40] )
            for k rows, where k = len(my_array)//num_col
    """
    my_array = shapeshifter(num_col=num_col, my_array=data)
    rows = [my_array[index] for index in range(len(my_array))]
    res = []
    for index in range(len(rows)):
        res.append( max(rows[index]) )
    return res
```

So far, the code is fine. I checked it with the following:

```
check1 = looper(2)
check2 = looper(4)
print(check1)
>> [2.0, 4.0, ..., 38.0, 40.0] 
print(len(check1))
>> 20
print(check2)
>> [4.0, 8.0, ..., 36.0, 40.0] 
print(len(check2))
>> 10
```

So far so good. Now here is my problem.

```
def metalooper(col_ls, my_array=data):
    """
    This function calls 'looper' - which calls
    'shapeshifter' - for every 'col' in 'col_ls'.

    EX:
        j_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
        ==> col_ls = [2,4,8,16,32]
        ==> looper(2), looper(4),
            looper(8), ..., looper(32)
        ==> shapeshifter(2), shapeshifter(4),
            shapeshifter(8), ..., shapeshifter(32)
                such that looper(2^j) ==> shapeshifter(2^j)
                for j in j_list
    """
    res = []
    for col in col_ls:
        res.append(looper(num_col=col))
    return res

j_list = [2,4,8,16,32]
check3 = metalooper(j_list)
```

Running the code above provides this error:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

With `40 data points`, the array can be reshaped into `2 columns` of `20 rows`, or `4 columns` of `10 rows`, or `8 columns` of `5 rows`, BUT at `16 columns`, the array cannot be reshaped without clipping data since `40/16 ≠ integer`. I believe this is the problem with my code, but I do not know how to fix it.

I am hoping there is a way to cutoff the *last* values in *each* row that do not fit in each window. If this is not possible, I am hoping I can append zeroes to fill the entries that maintain the size of the original array, so that I can remove the zeroes after. Or maybe even some complicated `if` - `try` - `break` block. What are some ways around this problem?

Comment: I ran this in a loop for `ncol` in `columns`. When it iterates the `2**4 # 16` window sizes, it will do the windows from `[1,2,...,16],[17,...,32], [33,...,40]`. That last window was unwanted because it was shortened. So I used `length = len(data)` to compare `crit = length/num_col` with `floor(crit)`; if they are equal, then the array won't be shortened. Otherwise, I just delete the last array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will give you what you want in one step:

```
def windowFunc(a, window, f = np.max):
    return np.array([f(i) for i in np.split(a, range(window, a.size, window))])
```

with default `f`, that will give you a array of maximums for your windows.

Generally, using [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) and `range`, this will let you split into a (possibly ragged) list of arrays:

```
def shapeshifter(num_col, my_array=data):    
    return np.split(my_array, range(num_col, my_array.size, num_col))
```

You need a list of arrays because a 2D array can't be ragged (every row needs the same number of columns)

If you *really* want to pad with zeros, you can use [`np.lib.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
def shapeshifter(num_col, my_array=data):
    return np.lib.pad(my_array, (0, num_col - my.array.size % num_col), 'constant',  constant_values = 0).reshape(-1, num_col)
```

**Warning:**

It is also technically possible to use, for example, [`a.resize(32,2)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) which will create an `ndArray` padded with zeros (as you requested).  *But* there are some big caveats:

1. You would need to calculate the second axis because `-1` tricks don't work with `resize`.
2. If the original array `a` is referenced by anything else, `a.resize` will fail with the following error:

   ```
   ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
   by another array in this way.  Use the resize function
   ```
3. The `resize` function (i.e. `np.resize(a)`) is not equivalent to `a.resize`, as instead of padding with zeros it will loop back to the beginning.

Since you seem to want to reference `a` by a number of windows, `a.resize` isn't very useful.  But it's a rabbit hole that's easy to fall into.

**EDIT:**

Looping through a list is slow.  If your input is long and windows are small, the `windowFunc` above will bog down in the `for` loops.  This should be more efficient:

```
def windowFunc2(a, window, f = np.max):
    tail = - (a.size % window)
    if tail == 0:
        return f(a.reshape(-1, window), axis = -1)
    else:
        body = a[:tail].reshape(-1, window)
        return np.r_[f(body, axis = -1), f(a[tail:])]
```

Comment: I do not want to pad with zeroes, that was helpfuI! `shapeshifter` runs smoorhly, and I can look up how to extract each array for sums with this. As for ragged, does ragged mean the arrays are of different sizes? As for the first function `windowFunc`, I get that `a` is the data array; is window the size of the row? And what is default `f` ? I'm guessing `f` is an array because of `f = np.max`.

Comment: "Ragged" indeed means the "rows" are of different lengths.  "Ragged" arrays aren't possible with numpy.   In `windowFunc`,  `window` is equivalent to `num_col` in your code.  `f` is a function which allows you to change what you want to do with the blocks.  When `f=np.max` then you're getting the maximum of the window (i.e. `f(i)` is `np.max(i)`), but you can also do `f=np.mean`, `f=np.sum` etc.

Comment: Those tricks with `f` are useful. I can't believe it was literally one step.

Comment: Turning loopy code into a single vectorized process is the strength of `numpy`.  Some of the wizards around here can do magic with `np.einsum` and `np.lib.stride_tricks` that will crunch a page of loopy code into a few statements that run in a fraction of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generalized way to reshape with truncation:

```
def reshape_and_truncate(arr, shape):
    desired_size_factor = np.prod([n for n in shape if n != -1])
    if -1 in shape:  # implicit array size
        desired_size = arr.size // desired_size_factor * desired_size_factor
    else:
        desired_size = desired_size_factor
    return arr.flat[:desired_size].reshape(shape)
```

Which your `shapeshifter` could use in place of `reshape`

Comment: I got this error when I ran this code:     `desired_size_factor = np.prod([n for n in shape if n != -1])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`     I like the idea of truncating in the function though, something to play with.

Comment: Calling convension is `reshape_and_truncate(arr, (-1, col))`, not `reshape_and_truncate(arr, -1, col)`. Should have made that clear

Comment: That was a careless mistake on my part, it was clear. It's a tuple in `reshape` too.