# How to find the max values of reshape-able array1 in a rolling window of variable size given array1 and array2 are equal length before padding?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, reshape

> > IGNORE EVERYTHING AND SKIP TO **EDIT** AT THE BOTTOM FOR CONDENSED EXPLANATION

**FULL QUESTION:**
How can I find the index of the max values of a reshape-able array of observed values in a rolling window of variable size given that the array of observed values corresponds to an array of observation times, and given that both arrays must be padded at identical indices?

**SHORT PREFACE:**

(I am having trouble fixing a code that is long and has a lot of moving parts. As such, I have only provided information I feel necessary to address my question and have left out other details that would make this post even longer than it is, though I can post a workable version of the code if requested.)

**SETUP:**

I have a text file containing times of observations and observed values at those times. I read the contents of the text file into the appropriate lists with the goal of performing a 'maximum self-similarity test', which entails finding the maximum value in a rolling window over an entire list of values; however, the first rolling window is 2 elements wide (`check indices 0 and 1, then 2 and 3, ..., len(data)-1 and len(data)`), then 4 elements wide, then 8 elements wide, etc. Assuming an array of 100 elements (I actually have around 11,000 data points), the last rolling window that is 8 elements wide will be disregarded because it is incomplete. To do this (with some help [from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114460/is-there-a-way-to-reshape-an-array-that-does-not-maintain-the-original-size-or)), I first defined a function to reshape an array such that it can be called by a parent function.

```
def shapeshifter(ncol, my_array=data):
    my_array = np.array(my_array)
    desired_size_factor = np.prod([n for n in ncol if n != -1])
    if -1 in ncol:  # implicit array size
        desired_size = my_array.size // desired_size_factor * desired_size_factor
    else:
        desired_size = desired_size_factor
    return my_array.flat[:desired_size].reshape(ncol)
```

The parent function that calls this will loop over each row to find the maximums.

```
def looper(ncol, my_array=data):
    my_array = shapeshifter((-1, ncol))
    rows = [my_array[index] for index in range(len(my_array))]
    res = []
    for index in range(len(rows)):
        res.append( max(rows[index]) )
    return res
```

And `looper` is called by a grandparent function that will change the size of the window for which the maximum values are obtained.

```
def metalooper(window_size, my_array=data):
    outer = [looper(win) for win in window_size]
    return outer
```

The next line calls the grandparent function, which in turns calls the sub-functions. In the line below, `window_size` is a predefined list of window sizes (ex: `[2,4,8,16,...]`).

```
ans = metalooper(window_size)
```

**PURPOSE (can remove if unnecessary):**

The function `metalooper` should return a list of sublists, for which each sublist contains the maximum elements of the rolling window. I then "normalize" (for lack of a better word) each value in the sublists by taking the logarithmic value of each maximum, only then to sum the elements of each sublist (such that the number of sums equals the number of sublists). Each sum is then divided by its respective weight, which gives the y-values that will be [plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9g5U.png) against the window sizes. This plot should be piecewise (linear or power-law).

**PROBLEM:**

My array of data points only contains the observed values and not the times (all of which I have converted into hours) that correspond to the observations. The times are not consecutive, so there may be an observation at 4 hrs, another at 7 hrs, another at 7.3 hrs, etc. My first mistake is not padding zeroes for non-consecutive times (ex: `observation_1` at `4 hrs`, `observation_2` at `6 hours` ==> `observed_value = 0` at `5 hrs`) as I should have moved the rolling window over the hours of observation (ex: window size of 2 means between [0,2) hours, [2,4) hours, etc) instead of the observed values at those times. However, my problem is compounded by the fact that there are also duplicate hours that fit within a window (ex: if multiple observations are made at 1 and 1.1 hours within a window of [0,2); regardless, I should find the maximum observed value in each rolling window, which entails knowing which observed values correspond to which times of observation *without disregarding* padded zeroes. However, how can I efficiently pad zeroes at identical indices in both lists? I am aware that I can `floor` the hours of observation to check which window an observed value should fall into. However, I am unsure how to proceed after this point as well - if I can pad both lists and if could find the index of the maximum observed value for each window, I can then us that index to get the desired observed value and the corresponding time of observation; I do not know how to do this or where to begin with this as my approach with for-looping lists is extremely slow. I would appreciate any help or advice on how to fix this. (Apologies for the length of this post, not sure how to condense beyond this). I would prefer to adapt my existing approach, but am open to alternatives if my method is too ridiculous.

**EDIT:**

To see how these functions work, let's use an example list `data`.

```
>> data = np.array(np.linspace(1,20,20))
# data corresponds to the observed values and not the observation times,
# below is a proof of concept using the values in data

>> print(shapeshifter((-1,2))) # 2 columns, -1 is always there
[[  1.   2.]
 [  3.   4.]
 [  5.   6.]
 [  7.   8.]
 [  9.  10.]
 [ 11.  12.]
 [ 13.  14.]
 [ 15.  16.]
 [ 17.  18.]
 [ 19.  20.]]

>> print(looper(2)) # get maximum in window_size (AKA length of each row) of 2 for each row of reshaped array via shapeshifter
[2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, 20.0]

def window_params(dataset=data): # concerned with window_size
    numdata = len(dataset) ## N = 11764
    lim = np.floor(np.log2(numdata)) ## last term of j = 13
    time_sc_index = np.linspace(1, lim, num=lim) ## j = [1,2,3,...,floor(log_2(N))=13]
    window_size = [2**j for j in time_sc_index] ## scale = [2,4,8,...,8192]
    block_size = np.floor([numdata/sc for sc in window_size]) ## b_j (sc ~ scale)
    return numdata, time_sc_index, window_size, block_size

numdata, time_sc_index, window_size, block_size = window_params()

>> print(window_size)
[2.0, 4.0, 8.0, 16.0]

>> print(metalooper(window_size)) # call looper for each window_size
[[2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, 20.0], [4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0, 20.0], [8.0, 16.0], [16.0]]
```

My issue is that these observations each correspond to different times. The list of times can be something like

```
times = [0, 4, 6, 6, 9, ...] # times are floored, duplicate times correspond to multiple observations at floored times
```

I need have a list of consecutive times `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]`, each of which correspond to an observed value from the list `data` (as each data point is observed at a specific time). My goal is to find the maximum observed value in each window of times. Using the times above, the observed value at `time=0` is `data[0]` and the observed value at `time=1` is `0` since there is no observation at that time. Similarly, I would use the maximum observed value at duplicate times; in other words, I have 2 observations at `time=6`, so I would want the maximum observed value at that time. While my windows roll over only observed values, I actually need the windows to roll over all hours (including `time=1` per this example) to find the maximum observed values at those times. In such a case, rolling a window over a time range that contains duplicate times should only count one of the duplicate times - specifically the one that corresponds to the maximum observed value at that time. My thinking is to pad zeroes into both lists (`times` and `data`) such that the index of `times` corresponds to the index of `data`. I'm trying to find an efficient way to proceed, though I'm having trouble figuring out a way to proceed at all.

Comment: Your question is too big and unclear for this forum.  My eyes just glaze over trying understand the context, much less identify the question.  Good SO questions have code and matrices that we can copy-n-paste to a script or running Python session, and experiment.

Comment: I realize it is quite the eye-sore. I will update the post later tonight with workable examples when I get off work.

Comment: @hpaulj I edited the post. It may suffice to read the EDIT and ignore everything above except for the code snippets that define functions.